# Can I iterate through an array in C# using something like a foreach

Tags: c#

I would like to do something like a foreach on an array of strings. I know I can do it with a for loop and incrementing but just wondering if there is something similar to the foreach:

```
foreach (var test in testlist)
```

Thanks

Comment: This is the sort of thing you could easily test yourself before asking.

Comment: My fault there. Sorry but I did test it out and got errors that I thought were there because I was doing something that was not possible. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Though there are downvotes to this question because the OP didn't seem to have tested his theory before asking. The close vote is invalid. This IS a real question, and it is NOT difficult to understand.

Comment: @rock: The reason it's not a real question is because the answer is "Yes". I tried to submit that as an answer three different times, but it keeps telling me that it's too short. Pretty good clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, like this

```
string[] arr = {"a", "aa", "aaa"};

foreach(string item in arr)
{
    Console.WriteLine("array element: " + item);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Array types derive from the System.Array class.  This is its declaration:

```
public abstract class Array : ICloneable, IList, ICollection, 
    IEnumerable, IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
{
    // etc..
}
```

It implements IEnumerable, that means that the foreach statement is supported.

Comment: +1 For the IEnumerable mention. I have seen my share of methods having array or List parameters when 99% of them could be IEnumerable

Comment: while technically correct this is a bit misleading. In particular it doesn't mention that concrete array types will implement `IEnumerable<T>`. And that `foreach` will not use the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` method.

Comment: Well, the jitter is entirely free to implement the "if it walks, swims and quacks like a duck then it's a duck" rule.  It certainly does, it generates code that's identical to a for() loop.  Very efficient, no bounds checks.  But yes, the SZArrayHelper class implements `GetEnumerator<T>()` for cases where a conversion to IEnumerator<> is required.

Answer (score 1):

The example you gave is correct.

```
string[] mystrings = GetArrayOfStrings();
foreach(String s in mystrings) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: If testlist is an array, then you aready have the answer, since an array implements `IEnumerable`.

```
foreach (var test in testlist)
{

}
```

Comment: converting to a list is not necessary and just adds system overhead.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring - good point. Thanks!

Comment: Don't convert to a `List`, anything that accepts `IEnumerable` will accept an array. The `ToList` method is expensive, and completely unnecessary here.

Comment: @Cody Gray - thanks for the feedback.  I edited my answer to reflect your feedback.